# Backbone with Marionette and Kendo: sample project anyone?

Tags: backbone.js, kendo-ui

does anyone have a sample project that uses Backbone with Marionette and Kendo? I've read everything I can find on the subject, but I can't find an example of how to define Kendo so I can create grids, treeviews and all the other funky widgets I'd like to use in my project.

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this article that I wrote? http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-11-26/backbone_and_kendo_ui_a_beautiful_combination.aspx

It contains a handful of JSFiddle samples that show how to integrate them.